# Can't build Facebooks HHVM from Github (git submodule init)

Tags: facebook, ubuntu, github, hhvm

When I run these steps:

```
mkdir dev
cd dev
git clone git://github.com/facebook/hhvm.git
cd hhvm
git submodule init
export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=`pwd`/..
export HPHP_HOME=`pwd`
cd ..
```

url: https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Building-and-installing-HHVM-on-Ubuntu-12.04

I get stuck at the `git submodule init` I get the error: `Submodule 'hphp/submodules/folly' () registered for path 'hphp/submodules/folly'`

I have no clue what it means and it doesn't look like a fatal error...

UPDATE:
`git submodule sync` does sync php/submodules/folly but still the same error...

Answer (score 1):

I would try:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

And make sure that "`Submodule 'xxx' registered for path 'yyy'`" is indeed an *error* message: it looks like a standard answer for a `git submodule init` command.
From the [`git submodule` book page](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-6.html):

> The `rack` directory is there, but empty.
>   You must run two commands:

- `git submodule init` to initialize your local configuration file, and
- `git submodule update` to fetch all the data from that project and check out the appropriate commit listed in your superproject:

  ```
  $ git submodule init
  Submodule 'rack' (git://github.com/chneukirchen/rack.git) registered for path 'rack'
  $ git submodule update
  Initialized empty Git repository in /opt/myproject/rack/.git/
  remote: Counting objects: 3181, done.
  remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1534/1534), done.
  remote: Total 3181 (delta 1951), reused 2623 (delta 1603)
  Receiving objects: 100% (3181/3181), 675.42 KiB | 173 KiB/s, done.
  Resolving deltas: 100% (1951/1951), done.
  Submodule path 'rack': checked out '08d709f78b8c5b0fbeb7821e37fa53e69afcf433'
  ```

I prefer running only one command:

```
git submodule update --init
```